# How we can omit the subjects in "not only but also" structure?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

When we can omit the subject (or sometimes the verb) in the second part of "not only... but also" structure?

I have seen some examples:

1. Not only is he handsome but also intelligent
2. Not only does he speak English but he also speaks French

In the first example the "he is" is omitted, however in the latter the "he speaks" seems to be mandatory, hence we cannot write "Not only does he speak English but also French".

I want to know in which situations we can prevent repeating the subject in the second part? Only when we want to mention an adjective? Or every time that we have similar subjects we can ignore it in the "but also" part?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Those are all correct, and so are others. You can optionally delete repeated material in conjoined clauses (clauses connected with _and, but, or_) via the rule of [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20conjunction%20reduction), which is widely applied in English.

Comment: (1) is incorrect. It should be *He is not only handsome but also intelligent.* or *Not only is he handsome, he is also intelligent.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat [Wren and Martin](https://www.google.com/books/edition/High_School_English_Grammar_Composition/CmgtDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) say that the following is acceptable: *not only is he foolish, but also obstinate* [(here)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/High_School_English_Grammar_Composition/CmgtDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Not+only+is+he%22+%22but+also%22&pg=PA132&printsec=frontcoverv).

Comment: You *can* say "but also French".

Comment: @linguisticturn: That example, too, is incorrect. The book goes on to contradict it in the next section: **“When conjunctions are used as correlatives, each of the correlated words should be placed *immediately before* the words to be connected; as, *He visited not only Agra, but also Delhi.* (Not) *He not only visited Agra, but also Delhi.*”** In formal, written English, what follows each part of the correlative pair should be parallel — both adjectives, both verbs, both independent clauses, etc. If not, you *will* hear from your editor.

Comment: Dear @JohnLawler I checked the conjunction reduction rules. It appears that in both situations we can ignore the subject, however, it really depends on whether to use the "comma" before the "but".

It means if we want to ignore the second subject and verb, then the second clause would be a dependent clause, thus we should not use "comma" --->

(1)Not only will I destroy his crayons, but I will also break his pencils.(independent clause)
(2)Not only will I destroy his crayon but also his pencils.(dependent clause)

---- [link](https://7esl.com/not-only-but-also/)
Thank you very much!

Comment: "He is not only handsome but also intelligent." 
"He speaks not only English, but also French (...but French also.)" In line with OP's question, these can at best be //Not only is he handsome but he is also intelligent./ Not only handsome, (but) he is intelligent also. (This is debatable.) 
"Not only does he speak English but he also (speaks) French.  I am not sure if we can use it as "Not only English, (but) he speaks also French.)